# PythonでプロセスIDから実行ファイルのパスを取得したい

Tags: python, python3, windows

お世話になっております。

PythonでプロセスIDから実行ファイルのパスを取得したいと考えています。
なお、プロセスIDは、何らかの方法で取得できているものとします。
それで、ざっと調べた限りだと、psutilを使えば簡単に実装できそうな感じなんですが、そのためだけにpsutilを入れるのも微妙なので、他に方法がないかと思っています。
Win32APIとかでできるようでしたら、その方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。
環境は、Windows10、Python3.7.5です。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: windowsのコマンド(wmic process get ProcessId,ExecutablePath)を実行して、pidからパスを引き当てる案はいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。wmicを使うのはよさそうですね。ただ、外部のプログラムを起動しないといけないので、若干処理に時間がかかるのが難点ですが。

Comment: 実際に動かしてみました、wmicを実行するとけっこう時間がかかるので、応答時間が心配でしたが、プロセスを限定すると結構早いです。wmicを勉強してみました。いろいろ情報が取得でき応用がききそうです。

Answer (score 2):

お世話になります。
結局今回の場合は、プロセスハンドルがわかっていたので、ctypesで取得することができました。
コメントや回答でアドバイスをくださり、ありがとうございました。
一応サンプルを掲載しておきます。

```
from ctypes import *

def getExeFileName(processHandle):
    exeFileName = create_unicode_buffer(wintypes.MAX_PATH)
    length = wintypes.DWORD(wintypes.MAX_PATH)
    if windll.Kernel32.QueryFullProcessImageNameW(processHandle, 0, exeFileName, byref(length)):
        return exeFileName.value
    else:
        return None
```

Answer (score 1):

wmicを使ったコードを実際に動かしてみました。
体感ですが、結構早いです。予想外でした。
wmicコマンドを起動するため、多用するとシステムに負荷を与えることは否めませんが、単発で使う分には問題ないと思います。。

## コード

```
import subprocess
pid = 16252
cmd = "wmic process where (ProcessId = " + str(pid ) + ") get ExecutablePath /format:CSV"
result = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
print(result.decode(encoding='shiftjis'))
```

## 出力結果

```
Node,ExecutablePath


XXXX,C:\Program Files (x86)\デジタル時計\デジタル時計.exe
```

XXXXはコンピュータ名です。伏せています。

## Pythonのバージョン

Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: 結局、今回の場合は、プロセスハンドルもわかっていたので、WindowsAPIで取得することにしました。詳しくは、回答として投稿しています。ありがとうございました。